# Eclipse remove src folder from structure

Tags: force.com, eclipse, ide, git

Is there a way to remove "src" folder as a default folder where all the components such as classes, pages, etc. reside? I have created a git repository using these instructions and my git folder structure does not have a src folder. Once I have my git in eclipse and I say add new class, it adds it under src folder and marks it as not committed in repository. Is there a way to change it?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be hard-wired into the Force.com IDE and so cannot be changed - see the [open source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/43eac2b8fa970bb46a9a513a939b8f6f3ff5cc24/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/internal/utils/Constants.java#L311).

It makes sense to have a dedicated folder for the various component types that package.xml identifies, so the pragmatic approach is to change your Git layout to match what the Force.com IDE requires.

(Alternatively other [Salesforce development tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools) might give you more choices.)

Comment: Pretty much *all* of them do, really. Force.com IDE 2 allowed arbitrary folders in the beta, but no idea if it'll continue to do so in the public release.

Comment: @sfdcfox You mention "Force.com IDE 2" - is that a significant re-write?

Comment: It's based on Salesforce DX, so I believe it's basically written from the ground up.